# jQuery deep clone isn't recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, deep-copy, cloneable

I am using js/jQuery and am attempting to create a true clone- I'm currently using jQuery for this. I would expect that in multi-level objects even the child objects should be deep cloned, but this appears to not be the case. Below is my test code and out put that leads me to believe that jQuery's deep clone doesn't actually  clone all the child objects.

has anyone written a true deep clone function, or is there a way of making jQuery's work as expected?

**Code:**

```
function deepClone (obj) {
    return $.extend(true, {}, obj);
};

var orig = {};
orig.companyData = {};
orig.companyData.TEST= 1;

var deep1 = deepClone(orig);
deep1.companyData.TEST= 0;

var deep2 = deepClone(orig);

console.log("orig: " + orig.companyData.TEST);
console.log("deep1: " + deep1.companyData.TEST);
console.log("deep2: " + deep2.companyData.TEST);
```

**Console Output:**

*Note: I expect 1, 0, 1*

```
0 
0
0
```

Comment: Could you add the code where orig and companyData are defined?

Comment: @Chitrang added it now

Comment: Seems to be working as expected... https://jsfiddle.net/ufm3vyvL/

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/8fsce0yq/

Comment: Your code given is already working as you expect. jQuery deep copy should work unless you are creating orig or companyData variable some other way like "new MyCustomObject(args)".

Comment: @Chitrang hmm, I see that it works in the fiddle but I just did more checks, it isn't working in my project still. when the companyData is populated it's companyData = $.parseJSON(jsonData); I don't see how this would be any different though... once it's parsed it's just an object just like other js object

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeqa5ucj/). It does log 1, 0, 1 as expected.

Comment: @JamesMadison: Please post your actual code and same short sample JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's extend function seems to work on most objects, some users have suggested that the issue may be with the way that my js object was created- I'm not sure what the culprit is, but my solution is below:

```
function deepClone(obj) {
    return $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(obj));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass both objects to be combined

```
function deepClone (obj1, obj2) {
    return $.extend(true, obj1, obj2);
};

var orig = {};
orig.companyData = {};
orig.companyData.TEST = 1;

var deep1 = deepClone(deep1, orig);
deep1.companyData.TEST= 0;
var deep2 = deepClone(deep2, orig);

console.log("orig: " + orig.companyData.TEST);
console.log("deep1: " + deep1.companyData.TEST);
console.log("deep2: " + deep2.companyData.TEST);
```

[See this code running](https://fiddle.jshell.net/x3559vtn/)

Comment: It still prints 0, 0, 0, which makes sense: When you are "passing in deep1" it's undefined.

Comment: I think he meant to make a blank object. `{}`

Comment: @JakeMorrison Look at my deepClone function, that's what I'm doing.

Comment: @JamesMadison You can try it [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/x3559vtn/), it works for me and returns 1,0,1

Comment: @claspina hmm look at my last comment on the original post

Comment: @JamesMadison When do you use this code does not work as expected? Which is exactly what comes out to you?

Comment: Why do you pass `undefined` to `deepClone`?